# How do I get to be "super" administrator with elevated priviledges in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, elevated-privileges

I had to format my pc and now I can't do the following things: Install games (get a prompt saying I'm not admin even though I am). I can't delete nor uninstall the stupid McAfee free subscription that installed itself. I can't edit any folder in program files, I can't install most things I want.

I googled my problem and was told to do the following:

open cmd.exe (I can individually open it as admin by right clicking)
Type in:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

All that did is add another user that has full admin rights.

This is what I see in my user screen:

[image: This is what I see in my user screen.]

I am on Tete, and "Administrator" account appeared after that cmd input.

Problems:

-I want Tete to be the super admin.

-I can't log in the Administrator account, requires password.

-I don't really want that account, just want to be admin myself.

-Even though it says admin under my name, I'm not full admin because I keep receiving access denied messages at times.

I really don't know what to do at this point; all websites say exactly the same thing.

Thank you very much for your time.

Tete

Comment: Update: Managed to remove administrator password and login, but for some reason, I still can't screw around with the program files folder... Also have no idea how to make Tete super admin... Thanks.

Comment: use my trick to run Explorer as admin on demand: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=144776 this is better compared to running all the time as admin.

Comment: Shouldn't just turning off UAC be enough?

Comment: Syberdoor: Not if you're not super admin to begin with. You're just not given access to some more advanced tasks.
@Magicandre1981: I logged into the admin account to do what I wanted to, and then went back to my user admin account. I'll try your method shortly, thanks.

Comment: installing games, uninstalling stuff etc can all be done without any hassle with UAC off. If UAC is on and it isn't autotriggered it also works to rightclick an executable and say "run as administrator" you don't have to be the "Administrator" account for any of those things. Also keep in mind some files belong to TrustedInstaller and those can not easily be manipulated even with Administrator account. An example would be the Program Files folder itself which you cannot delete with any account without claiming ownership beforehand.